# What is the difference between returning IList vs List, or IEnumerable vs List<Class>. I want to know which is better to return

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

What is the difference between returning IList vs List, or IEnumerable vs List.

I want to know which is better to return.

When we need to use one, what effect will it have on performance?

Comment: Basically, if you use IList or IEnumerable as return type, you can return ANY object that implements these interfaces. If you specify a concrete class, then you can return only that specific type.

Comment: There are some [guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx). And the best way to write performant code is to write simple, understandable code, and to have actual performance goals. Once everything is written, *measure* the performance, and only if things aren't performing well enough should you consider avoiding "simple, understandable" - but make sure you've also measured where the performance is poor and focus attention there. I've never had a situation where changing the return data type would make a significant difference.

Comment: In terms of performance, it doesn't matter which type you allow your function to return, but what concrete object you are returning.

Comment: Thanks Damien for share  "Guidelines for Collections" its really great article.

Comment: @Jcl that's not true. There is a performance difference (no matter how small): https://levelup.gitconnected.com/ilist-t-vs-list-t-performance-dad1688a374f?sk=3264a8bc1eedfbad2329e6e63af839e9

Comment: @DavidKlempfner that's very interesting and not intuitive to me when thinking at high level (although makes perfect sense), thanks for the link

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is no such a type that is *always* better to return. It's a decision you should make based on your design/performance/etc goals.

`IEnumerable<T>` is nice to use when you want to represent sequence of items, that you can iterate over, but you don't want to allow modifications(Add, Delete etc).

`IList<T>` gives you everything you could get using `IEnumerable<T>`, plus operations that give you more control over a collection: Add, Delete, Count, Index access etc.

`List<T>` is a concrete implementation of `IList<T>`. I would say that almost always it's better to expose `IList<T>` interface from your methods rather that `List<T>` implementation. And it's not just about lists - it's a basic design principle to prefer interfaces over concrete implementations.

Ok, now about non-generic versions `IEnumerable, IList, List`:
They actually came from very early versions of .NET framework, and life is much better using generic equivalents.

And few words about performance:
`IEnumerable<T>`(with `IEnumerator<T>`) is actually an iterator which allows you to defer some computations until later. It means that there is no need to allocate memory right away for storing amounts of data(of course, it's not the case when you have, say, array behind iterator). You can compute data gradually as needed. But it means that these computations might  be performed over and over again(say, with every `foreach` loop). On the other hand, with List you have fixed data in memory, with cheap Index and Count operations. As you see, it's all about compromise.

Comment: If client code calls a method that returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, the client code must now avoid multiple enumeration (e.g. by calling `ToList()`), because it is possible that (now or in the future) the method returns a sequence with _deferred execution_ - potentially of the _slow, expensive kind_. Much better, methods should prefer to return `IReadOnlyCollection<T>`, which is basically `IEnumerable<T>` with an additional `Count` property, and the implication that there is _no deferred execution_. Related (but lacking interfaces): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169389(v=vs.110).aspx.

Answer (score 4):

Concrete classes in parameters and results of methods make the strong dependency, while using interfaces don't. What does it mean?

If you'll change the implementation of your class, and will use `SynchroinizedCollection`, `LinkedList`, or something other instead of `List`, then you'll have to change your methods signature, exactly the type of return value.

After that you'll have to rebuild assemblies that use the class, but also you'll have to rewrite them.

However, if you're using one of `IEnumerable`, `IReadonlyCollection`, `ICollection`, or `IList` interfaces, you'll not have to rewrite and rebuild client assemblies. Thus, interfaces always preferred classes in parameters and results. (But remember, we're talking about dependencies between different assemblies. With the same assembly this rule is not so important.)

The question is, what interface to use? It depends on requirements of client classes (use cases). F.e. if you're processing elements one by one, use `IEnumerable<T>`, and if you need a count of elements, use `IReadonlyCollection<T>`. Both of these interfaces are co-variance that is convenient for a type-casting.

If you need write abilities (`Add`, `Remove`, `Clear`) or non co-variance read only abilities (`Contains`), use `ICollection<T>`. Finally, if you need a random indexed access, use `IList<T>`.

As for performance, the invocation of interface's method a bit slower, but it's insignificant difference. You may be patient about this.